# Why I am getting TLE on Lightoj 1176 problem?

Tags: c

Problem: Ekka and his friend Dokka decided to buy a cake. They both love cakes and that's why they want to share the cake after buying it. As the name suggested that Ekka is very fond of odd numbers and Dokka is very fond of even numbers, they want to divide the cake such that Ekka gets a share of N square centimeters and Dokka gets a share of M square centimeters where N is odd and M is even. Both N and M are positive integers.

They want to divide the cake such that N * M = W, where W is the dashing factor set by them. Now you know their dashing factor, you have to find whether they can buy the desired cake or not.

Input
Input starts with an integer T (≤ 10000), denoting the number of test cases.

Each case contains an integer W (2 ≤ W < 2^63). And W will not be a power of 2.

Output
For each case, print the case number first. After that print "Impossible" if they can't buy their desired cake. If they can buy such a cake, you have to print N and M. If there are multiple solutions, then print the result where M is as small as possible

Time Limit: 2 second(s)

I've tried on sample inputs and got same result as the output.

Sample Input

3

10

5

12

Output for Sample Input

Case 1: 5 2

Case 2: Impossible

Case 3: 3 4

My code:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<math.h>
   int main()
   {
    int t,k;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(k=1;k<=t;k++)
    {


    int a,i,j=1,c;

    scanf("%d",&a);

    for(i=2;i<sqrt(a)+2;i++)
    {
        if(a%i==0 && i%2!=0)

                 c=i;
    }
    int b=a/c;
    if(b%2==0 && b*c==a)
       printf("Case %d: %d %d\n",k,c,b);
    else
        printf("Case %d: Impossible\n",k);



    }
    return 0;
   }
```

The Light OJ given TLE to my solution.

Comment: Normally one would use profilers and other timing techniques to figure out hotspots and bottlenecks in the code. But with online judges/competition sites it's impossible, not only because you can't use such tools or even in-code timing, but also because they very seldom tell you the data they give as input for your program. If you want to learn C the "proper" way, get some books to read, or take a couple of classes. That will make you a much better programmer than such sites.

Comment: The problem statement says that W can be as large as 2^63, which won't fit in an `int` variable. Try using `long long` instead. Your code may very well have other problems too.

Comment: If `a` is prime, what value will `c` have after your loop?

Comment: Besides that: Welcome to SO. Please try to find a useful title for your question. For anyone not participating in any of those "coding contest" stuff, that title does not contain any meaning and might not attract many readers.

Comment: @Gerhardh If a is prime the answer will be  'Impossible'. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Are you sure? You never assign a value to `c` in this case and after the loop you do `b=a/c;` This is undefined behaviour and might result in division by zero error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is `giving TLE`.

May be you need to optimise it a little.

One thing I am suggesting is:

If the number W is `not divisible by 2`, print `"Impossible"`.

If the number W is divisible by 2, keep dividing the number by 2, until it `becomes an odd number.`

So, the odd number generated will be one share and `W/odd_number` will be other share.

Comment: Since W is integer you can test for even by using "W & 1 = 0" and division by 2 by using "W >> 2"

Comment: Should not it be W >> 1?